# pythonテキストファイル（log）のCSV化

Tags: python, python3

機器のログを取得し、CSV化しようとしましたが、ログが100万行程度あり、VBAでは全件表示できず、処理できない状態です。
そこで、pythonでログをCSV化しようとしておりますが、以下2点をどの様にすればよいのか全く分からない状況です。

＜分からないこと＞
①dataコマンドで表示した日時をID、MAC Addressなどの列の左側に追記したい
②ID、MAC Addressなどのヘッダーがコマンドを実行する度に表示されるので、CSV化する場合は、一番最初だけにしたい
③CSV化するにあたり、date、wlc# show ap-discovered、   Discovered APs and Stations(4249 entries)など不要な
　コマンド等は削除したい

＜記載したコード＞
sample.py

```
file_name = "C:/Work/before.log"

with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    newlines = line.split()
    print(newlines)
```

＜その他＞
before.log→機器から出力したログ（100万行程度ですが、数行だけ掲載しております）
after.csv→before.logを加工し、実現したい形式

before.log

```
date
Tue Nov 11 00:00:00 JST 2022
wlc# show ap-discovered

ID     MAC Address       Type          Channel Confirmed-Channel SSID                             BSSID             Last            Previous  Current   Pkts Rx  RF Band       Name            

40     aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff AP            6       6                 samplesamplesample               11:22:33:44:55:66 00d:00h:00m:00s 0         -77       313382   802.11gn      AP1        
40     gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll AP            6       7                 samplesamplesample               22:33:44:55:66:77 00d:00h:00m:01s 0         -75       2840     802.11gn      AP2
    Discovered APs and Stations(4249 entries)
date
Tue Nov 11 00:05:00 JST 2022
wlc# show ap-discovered

ID     MAC Address       Type          Channel Confirmed-Channel SSID                             BSSID             Last            Previous  Current   Pkts Rx  RF Band       Name            

40     aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff AP            6       6                 samplesamplesample               11:22:33:44:55:66 00d:00h:00m:00s 0         -77       313382   802.11gn      AP1        
40     gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll AP            6       7                 samplesamplesample               22:33:44:55:66:77 00d:00h:00m:01s 0         -75       2840     802.11gn      AP2
date
Tue Nov 11 00:10:00 JST 2022
wlc# show ap-discovered

ID     MAC Address       Type          Channel Confirmed-Channel SSID                             BSSID             Last            Previous  Current   Pkts Rx  RF Band       Name            

40     aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff AP            6       6                 samplesamplesample               11:22:33:44:55:66 00d:00h:00m:00s 0         -77       313382   802.11gn      AP1        
40     gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll AP            6       7                 samplesamplesample               22:33:44:55:66:77 00d:00h:00m:01s 0         -75       2840     802.11gn      AP2
    Discovered APs and Stations(4249 entries)
```

after.csv

```
Day,Month,Date,Time,ID,MAC Address,Type,Channel,Confirmed-Channel,SSID,BSSID,Last,Previous,Current,Pkts,Rx,RF,Band,Name            
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:00,40,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,AP,6,6,samplesamplesample,11:22:33:44:55:66,00d:00h:00m:00s,0,-77,313382,802.11gn,AP1
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:00,40,gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll,AP,6,6,samplesamplesample,22:33:44:55:66:77,00d:00h:00m:00s,0,-77,313382,802.11gn,AP2        
Tue,Nov,11,00:05:00,40,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,AP,6,6,samplesamplesample,11:22:33:44:55:66,00d:00h:00m:00s,0,-77,313382,802.11gn,AP1
Tue,Nov,11,00:05:00,40,gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll,AP,6,6,samplesamplesample,22:33:44:55:66:77,00d:00h:00m:00s,0,-77,313382,802.11gn,AP2
```

コード例をご提示いただき、ご教示いただけると助かります。

---

追記

```
file_name = "C:/Work/before.log"

# 追記
out = open('output.txt','w')

with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    # lines = f.readlines()

    print('Day,Month,Date,Time,ID,MAC Address,Type,Channel,Confirmed-Channel,SSID,BSSID,Last,Previous,Current,Pkts,Rx,RF,Band,Name')

    # Fileを1行ずつ読む
    line = f.readline()
    while line:

        # date 行だったら次の行を読んで４列だけ取得してカンマでつないで date_csv 変数に記憶
        if line.startswith('date'):
            line = f.readline()
            date = line.split()[:4]
            date_csv = ','.join(date) + ','

        # 数字から始まってたら記憶した date_csv とその行を , つなぎにしてものを１行で出力
        if line[0] >= '0' and line[0] <= '9':
            # print(date_csv + ','.join(line.split()))
            print(date_csv + ','.join(line.split()))
            
        line = f.readline()

        # 追記↓
        out.write(line + "\n")
# 追記↓
out.close()
```

out.txt出力結果

```
wlc# show ap-discovered



ID     MAC Address       Type          Channel Confirmed-Channel SSID                             BSSID             Last            Previous  Current   Pkts Rx  RF Band       Name            



40     aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff AP            6       6                 samplesamplesample               11:22:33:44:55:66 00d:00h:00m:00s 0         -77       313382   802.11gn      AP1        

40     gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll AP            6       7                 samplesamplesample               22:33:44:55:66:77 00d:00h:00m:01s 0         -75       2840     802.11gn      AP2

date

wlc# show ap-discovered



ID     MAC Address       Type          Channel Confirmed-Channel SSID                             BSSID             Last            Previous  Current   Pkts Rx  RF Band       Name            



40     aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff AP            6       6                 samplesamplesample               11:22:33:44:55:66 00d:00h:00m:00s 0         -77       313382   802.11gn      AP1        

40     gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll AP            6       7                 samplesamplesample               22:33:44:55:66:77 00d:00h:00m:01s 0         -75       2840     802.11gn      AP2

date
```

Comment: ちなみにそもそもCSVで通知するモードとか、ログデータをCSVに変換する補助ツールとかはありませんか？ 最近の機器だとありそうですけど。

Comment: マニュアルを見ましたが、CSV通知モードはありませんでした。また補助ツールは、専用のアプライアンスを購入する必要があるため、用意できない状況です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readlines() を使うとメモリ上にすべてのファイル内容を取得してしまうので
１００万行単位だとメモリ的に厳しいかもしれません

基本的には date 行をよんだら date の内容を覚えておいて
レコード行をよんだときに date とあわせて吐き出してしまえば
過去呼んだ部分を覚えておくのは最新の date 内容だけでいいはずです

こんな感じでしょうか

```
file_name = "C:/Work/before.log"

with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    # lines = f.readlines()

    print('Day,Month,Date,Time,ID,MAC Address,Type,Channel,Confirmed-Channel,SSID,BSSID,Last,Previous,Current,Pkts,Rx,RF,Band,Name')

    # Fileを1行ずつ読む
    line = f.readline()
    while line:

        # date 行だったら次の行を読んで４列だけ取得してカンマでつないで date_csv 変数に記憶
        if line.startswith('date'):
            line = f.readline()
            date = line.split()[:4]
            date_csv = ','.join(date) + ','

        # 数字から始まってたら記憶した date_csv とその行を , つなぎにしてものを１行で出力
        if line[0] >= '0' and line[0] <= '9':
            print(date_csv + ','.join(line.split()))

        line = f.readline()
```

※　ログなので出力先は標準出力にしましたがリダイレクトなりすればファイルにはけると思いますし、固定ファイル出力するならwith open(file_name, 'w') みたいなコードにうめこんでもいいと思います

※　１文字目が数字ではじまるものをレコード行としましたが ③ の内容にどんなものがあるか不明なので正確にやるなら正規表現でマッチングしたほうがいいかもしれないです
その分判定コストが重くなるので１００万行分となると時間かかるかもですが

---

追記

ファイル出力版です

```
file_name = "C:/Work/before.log"

with open('output.txt','w') as out:
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
        # lines = f.readlines()

        out.write('Day,Month,Date,Time,ID,MAC Address,Type,Channel,Confirmed-Channel,SSID,BSSID,Last,Previous,Current,Pkts,Rx,RF,Band,Name\n')

        # Fileを1行ずつ読む
        line = f.readline()
        while line:

            # date 行だったら次の行を読んで４列だけ取得してカンマでつないで date_csv 変数に記憶
            if line.startswith('date'):
                line = f.readline()
                date = line.split()[:4]
                date_csv = ','.join(date) + ','

            # 数字から始まってたら記憶した date_csv とその行を , つなぎにしてものを１行で出力
            if line[0] >= '0' and line[0] <= '9':
                out.write(date_csv + ','.join(line.split()) + "\n")

            line = f.readline()
```

実行結果

```
Day,Month,Date,Time,ID,MAC Address,Type,Channel,Confirmed-Channel,SSID,BSSID,Last,Previous,Current,Pkts,Rx,RF,Band,Name
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:00,40,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,AP,6,6,samplesamplesample,11:22:33:44:55:66,00d:00h:00m:00s,0,-77,313382,802.11gn,AP1
Tue,Nov,11,00:00:00,40,gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll,AP,6,7,samplesamplesample,22:33:44:55:66:77,00d:00h:00m:01s,0,-75,2840,802.11gn,AP2
Tue,Nov,11,00:05:00,40,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,AP,6,6,samplesamplesample,11:22:33:44:55:66,00d:00h:00m:00s,0,-77,313382,802.11gn,AP1
Tue,Nov,11,00:05:00,40,gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll,AP,6,7,samplesamplesample,22:33:44:55:66:77,00d:00h:00m:01s,0,-75,2840,802.11gn,AP2
Tue,Nov,11,00:10:00,40,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,AP,6,6,samplesamplesample,11:22:33:44:55:66,00d:00h:00m:00s,0,-77,313382,802.11gn,AP1
Tue,Nov,11,00:10:00,40,gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll,AP,6,7,samplesamplesample,22:33:44:55:66:77,00d:00h:00m:01s,0,-75,2840,802.11gn,AP2
```

自分の環境ではサンプルの before.log に対しては動きました
もしだめなようならサンプルのログをもう少し長めにはってもらえると原因がわかるかもです

---

更に追記

readline のほうがわかりやすいかと思ってあえて使ったんですが
readline がどういう関数なのかわかりにくいみたいなので
よくあるファイルをイテレーターとして使って１行ずつ読む例です

```
file_name = "C:/Work/before.log"

out = open('output.txt','w')
# print('Day,Month,Date,Time,ID,MAC Address,Type,Channel,Confirmed-Channel,SSID,BSSID,Last,Previous,Current,Pkts,Rx,RF,Band,Name\n')

out.write('Day,Month,Date,Time,ID,MAC Address,Type,Channel,Confirmed-Channel,SSID,BSSID,Last,Previous,Current,Pkts,Rx,RF,Band,Name\n')

with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:

    # Fileを1行ずつ読む
    for line in f:

        # date 行だったら次の行を読んで４列だけ取得してカンマでつないで date_csv 変数に記憶
        if line.startswith('date'):
            line = f.__next__() # 次の行にループを進ませる (readline と同じ)
            date = line.split()[:4]
            date_csv = ','.join(date) + ','

        # 数字から始まってたら記憶した date_csv とその行を , つなぎにしてものを１行で出力
        if line[0] >= '0' and line[0] <= '9':
            output_line = date_csv + ','.join(line.split())
            # print(output_line)
            out.write(output_line + "\n")

out.close()
```

Comment: ご回答有難うございまいます。print(date_csv + ','.join(line.split()))をテキストに書きだそうとしていますが、うまくいかない助教です。flename = の次の行に、out = open('output.txt','w')を追記、line = f.readline()次の行に、out.writelines(line)を追記しました。

Comment: writelines は複数行の配列をわたすものです。１行だけかきたいなら out.write(line + "\n") でいけると思います

Comment: out.write(line + "\n")を入れてみましたが、なぜか、before.logに空白行が2行入ったoutput.txtができているだけです。

Comment: 追記しました。close 忘れてたりしないですか？ with を使えばかってに close されますが out = open('output.txt','w') だと close() が必要です

Comment: ちな書き込む文字列を便宜上 line って呼んでるだけだと思ってますが line って変数に入ってるのは入力文字列で、出力内容は print(date_csv + ','.join(line.split())) の部分です。なので out に書き込むのはこの部分を置き換える必要があります

Comment: 度々、ご回答有難うございます。ちょっと、色々と混乱してきたので、実際に書いたコードを質問欄に追記させていただきました。

Comment: ディスカッションに移動してくださいって言われたんですが、＜分からないこと＞にファイル書き込みの要件がなく、あくまでテキスト処理方法に関する当初の質問とずれてきているので、ファイル書き込みへの変更は別質問でしたほうがいいかもしれないです

Answer (score 0):

既に解決済みなので御参考です。Python3.8 で（賛否の議論の後に）導入された代入式（`:=`）を使ってみました。

```
file_name = 'C:/Work/before.log'

with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    print('Day,Month,Date,Time,ID,MAC Address,Type,'
          'Channel,Confirmed-Channel,SSID,BSSID,Last,'
          'Previous,Current,Pkts,Rx,RF,Band,Name')

    line = ''
    while line or (line := f.readline()):
        if line[:4] != 'date':
            line = ''
            continue
        date_info = f.readline().split()[:4]

        while f.readline()[:2] != 'ID': pass
        f.readline()  # read blank line
        while (line := f.readline())[:1].isdecimal():
            print(','.join(date_info + line.split()))
```